# Omnifaces send unload request after logout

Tags: primefaces, wildfly, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

I have a JSF 2.2 application which runs under Wildfly 10. We use Omnifaces 2.1. I tried to update to 2.6.3.
Now after a logout and login, I can not load the page again where the logout was called. I tried to debug the js file and it seems like the server is behind with one iteration. The javascript sends the unload request for example on the main.xhtml on logout. But it only calls the isUnloadRequest on server side after login so it ends up on a white page. (refresh again works of course) The log out is nothing special, simply invalidate and redirect. The login works with the Wildfly login module.

Any idea?

Comment: Is logout performed by ajax? Try non-ajax instead and let me know.

Comment: @BalusC
This one solved the problem, thank you! But seems like the GEB automatic tests still have issues. They not always click on the logout button, only soft resets the browser. This way after login this can also results an empty page because of an "invalid" unload request.

Comment: Can you try today's 2.6.4-SNAPSHOT and confirm if that works for your case? See also https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/392

Comment: @BalusC
Thank you but still not works. :(
I made a little test which doesn't do anything else just login and leave the logout for GEB.  Second or third login just fail with an empty page. It's very strange because the main page doesn't have any ViewScope bean, and it should not have to register the Unload.JS. Somehow it's still send an unload request.

Comment: That fix should at least fix the logout via ajax (can you reconfirm?). Not sure about GEB as I've never used it. I've at least never faced this problem with [Arquillian (Selenium/Graphene/JUnit)](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/test/java/org/omnifaces/test/cdi/viewscoped/ViewScopedIT.java). Every `@Test` already implicitly starts with a fresh new session and doesn't reuse the previous one. Perhaps you should instruct GEB in some way to always start every `@Test` with a fresh new session.

Comment: @BalusC I have tried it. Ajax="true" still not works with the snapshot version, just ajax="false".

Comment: @BalusC Seems like GEB only delete the cookies between two tests. I tried it and you can reproduce it manually. If you "logout" with deleting the cookies the result is the same. It's enough to delete the Session ID cookie.